# Running Code after a button is clicked with GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm wondering how I can run a piece of code after a user presses a button. In this case I'm asking the user to enter their name in a textField (Shown below)

```
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.setBounds(104, 271, 517, 48);
    contentPane.add(textField);
```

Then after the user has clicked Next I'd like the GUI to move to another line of code that changes the layout of the GUI.

I'm assuming I'd need to put something in here that would then run another line of code elsewhere,

```
    JButton Next = new JButton("Next");
    Next.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        //Would I need to put something here?
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        }
    });
```

#### Details

What I'm trying to do is create a game. I want the user to be able to input their name, then I want the user to be able to click a button that says 'next', and then once that button is pressed I would like things in the Java Program to change. I.E, text to change to something else.

After the user would input their details for the game (Name, preferred Class, Gender, etc), I'd have the Components be removed and then have a image and at some point, their Health.

Comment: Looks like you are going about this the wrong way. Explain what you are trying to do and show us what the GUI looks like. A button that changes the GUI layout sounds very fishy.

Comment: Are you changing only the text or the components themselves?

Comment: It looks to me like you want either a `CardLayout` or a `JDialog` / `JOptionPane` to take the initial details and only then display the main frame.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse's IDE with the Swing Plugin and I don't see CardLayout or JDialog, nor do I see JOptionPane in the GUI Creator.

Comment: Then your best bet is to learn how to code it by hand. I linked the tutorial in your previous question.

Comment: Don't use a null layout (i.e. setBounds). Instead use [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) or combinations of them. Also your variable names should start with a lower case, see [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Instead of using TextField try with Swing's [JTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)

Comment: *"`TextField textField ..`"* should be `JTextField textField ..` (use theSwing based textfield, not the AWT one!).  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).   But I have to say I agree with @Frakcool and user1803551 about using layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CardLayout to change the GUI appearance. Each "screen" of your GUI is represented by a card. Certain events (like pressing a button) can trigger a new card to be shown, hence showing a new screen of your GUI.

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

class Game{  

   /* This JPanel will manage all the cards we create */ 
   JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout()); 

   JTextField jtfName;
   JButton    jbtName;
   String     name;

   Game(){

      JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Game");
      jfrm.setSize(200, 220);
      jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      /* Setup card 1: This card asks for a username
       * and then changes to the next screen when the 
       * user clicks the "next" button.
       */
      JPanel card1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      jtfName = new JTextField(15);
      jbtName = new JButton("Next");
      jbtName.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){  
            /* Make sure a username was entered */
            if (!jtfName.getText().equals("")){ 
               name = jtfName.getText();
               swapCards("card2");
            }
         }
      });
      card1.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
      card1.add(jtfName);
      card1.add(jbtName);

      /* Setup card 2 */
      JPanel card2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
      card2.add(new JLabel("Game stuff here ... "));

      /* Add cards to the controlling card. */
      cards.add(card1, "card1");
      cards.add(card2, "card2");

      /* Add the cards panel to the Frame and display */
      jfrm.add(cards);
      jfrm.setVisible(true);
   }

   /* Method to swap cards based on their name.
    * This is what actually changes the screen.
    */
   private void swapCards(String card){
      CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
      cl.show(cards, card);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         public void run(){
            new Game();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using netbeans , right click on your button under design tab and choose the event Mouse -> MouseClicked .
It will create a void that handles this event.
Enter your code that you want to ruen once the button is pressed .

Comment: I'm using Eclipse, but I'll try that anyways. Is there no quicker way to do it?

Comment: If you want a decent and maintainable gui code, don't use the netbeans wysiwyg. You need to add an ActionListener, not a MouseListener

Comment: I've did what Ayman Suggested but the Panels all stay there. Is there any way to change that?

Comment: @JordonMyers : did you read the other answers? You need an ActionListener and you need code in the actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){} method, if there's nothing there, it's obvious it won't do anything